# How to remove pair slash+doublequotes from a string?

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring

my string is:

```
"random-key1=\"value1\"; random-key2=\"value2\";";
```

and I need to extract 'value1' from it!

EDIT:
the string does have \" exactly like that!!!
\" is not 1 character! both are in the string!

the \" is really tricky here, I tried many different ways, and I cannot get it to work right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the first instance of the string that, as a human, I would write \", then you want:

```
NSRange rangeOfFirstSlashQuote = [string rangeOfString:@"\\\""];

// \\ will be parsed as a single \;
// \" will be parsed as a single "
```

You can then use `rangeOfString:options:range:` to find subsequently instances of the string.

So if you literally just want to find the first thing inside slash-quotes then that'll do it. If you wanted to build a dictionary of value by key you'd probably want `componentsSeparatedByString:@";"`, then for each component you could separate on `=` and proceed from there.

Comment: here is what I have: "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"; ..."    and I need to get the filename.value

Comment: That came from a foreign source? If it's meant to be HTTP then then the slashes shouldn't be in there, so either the sender is broken or — and I hate to ask because you've been categorical — are you definitely, definitely sure the slashes are there? No chance they're being added by whatever you're using for inspection?

Comment: I found the solution: NSURLResponse -suggestedFilename is what I needed, +1 and thanks for the help!